# assign wifi device name to variable

Tags: macos, unix

I'm running the following command to figure out which network interface is being used currently.

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep -C1 $(route get default | grep interface | awk '{print $2}')
```

How can I use that command and parse out the device name of that interface and then compare it to the device name of the Wi-Fi interface?

---

So I run the command above and this is what I get:

```
Hardware Port: Ethernet
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: a8:60:b6:03:0a:97
```

This is telling me that my ethernet port, or device en0 is the active network port on my computer. I want to assign en0 to a variable, say currentPort.

I will also run this command:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

This would be the results of that:

```
Hardware Port: Ethernet
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: a8:60:xx:xx:xx:xx

Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en1
Ethernet Address: 2c:f0:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

From this I want to pull the device name for my wifi, in this case en1 and assign it to another variable, say wifiPort.

So I should have currentPort=en0 and wifiPort=en1. I am hoping that I can then run an if then command that says is currentPort is not the same as wifiPort do one thing, if currentPort is the same as wifiPort, do something else.

Hope this helps explain things a little better.

---

This is what I'm working with right now, based on your help. echo $currentport and echo $wifiport doesn't give me any output and with the if commands, it echos "They are the same" regardless of what device I'm using.

```
#!/bin/bash

#currentport=`grep -A3 'Ethernet' t6.txt | grep "Device"| awk -F": " '{print $2}'`
currentport=`echo $a|grep -A3 'Ethernet'| grep "Device"| awk -F": " '{print $2}'`
echo $currentport

#wifiport=`grep -A3 'Wi-Fi' t5.txt | grep "Device"| awk -F": " '{print $2}'`
wifiport=`echo $b|grep -A3 'Wi-Fi'| grep "Device"| awk -F": " '{print $2}'`
echo $wifiport

if [[ $currentport == $wifiport ]]
then
    echo They are the same
else
    echo They are different
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Sample input and expected output?

Comment: I've added some sample output for the commands used.  What I'm not clear is what you want as the result.  Please clarify the desired output.

Comment: I want to get the device name (en0, en1, etc.) for the wifi port and the same for the  network interface being used currently and assign them to variables...the end game is to run part of a script if the device is using the wifi connection or exit the script if they are using something other than wifi. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @kbrem Please add the expected output in the question above with proper sample input. It will make tye question clearer.

Comment: @Mayank Porwal I updated the original question to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @kbrem Check my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Check out my original question...I included the mini script with they code you gave me. I'm not getting any output from it.

Comment: @kbrem Script looks fine to me. Just enclose the statements in `if` loop after `echo` commands in quotes ` '  ' `. Is it not working? If not, share your $a and $b also.

Comment: @MayankPorwal If I run that script (I took the if statement out to simplify things) in terminal, I just get blank lines where you would expect the output to be.

Comment: @kbrem This is because `$a` and `$b` variables I used were an example. You would need to use the actual variables which hold the output for  `networksetup` command.

Comment: @kbrem Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For `currentport`:

Assume the output of your `networksetup` command is stored in a file: `t6.txt`

```
Hardware Port: Ethernet
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: a8:60:b6:03:0a:97
```

Do this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/ currentport=`echo $a|grep -A3 'Ethernet'| grep "Device"| awk -F": " '{print $2}'`
mayankp@mayank:~/ echo $currentport
en0
```

For `wifiport`:

Assume the output of your `networksetup` command is stored in a file: `t5.txt`

```
Hardware Port: Ethernet
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: a8:60:xx:xx:xx:xx

Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en1
Ethernet Address: 2c:f0:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Do this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/ wifiport=`echo $b|grep -A3 'Wi-Fi'| grep "Device"| awk -F": " '{print $2}'`
mayankp@mayank:~/ echo $wifiport
en1
```

Now, you have both variables: `$currentport` and `$wifiport`.

Use `if` to do what you want:

```
if [[ $currentport == $wifiport ]]
then
<do your stuff>
else
<do other stuff>
fi
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating the .txt files....have the variable stored in memory?

Comment: I just added `echo $a` before the `grep command` and removed the filename from it. This should solve it. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd avoid using all those pipes, and just do this in awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR&&/interface/{i=$2} NR==FNR{next} index($0,"Device: "i)' \
 <(route get default) \
 RS= \
 <(networksetup -listallhardwareports)
```

The awk script first parses the `route` command's output to determine the interface to use, then sets `RS=` which forces awk into multi-line mode, which allows the `index()` command to be used as a condition for printing a record.

And if you want just the WiFi port, the awk script is even simpler, because you don't need to parse the `route` command:

```
awk 'index($0,"Hardware Port: Wi-Fi")' RS= <(networksetup -listallhardwareports)
```

And if you want to compare the results, i.e. determine whether you are currently using WiFi, it's easy enough to wrap the commands you need in process substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash

currentPort=$(
    awk '/interface/{print $2;exit}' <(route get default)
)
wifiPort=$(
    awk 'index($0,"Hardware Port: Wi-Fi") {
            sub(/.*Device: /,"");sub(/[[:space:]].*/,"")
            print; exit
        }' \
     RS= \
     <(networksetup -listallhardwareports)
)

if [[ "$wifiPort" = "$currentPort" ]]; then
    echo "I'm on WiFi!"
else
    echo "I'm NOT on WiFi!"
fi
```

Of course, you could also do this in bash alone, without the need for awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

junk=$(route get default)
[[ $junk =~ .*interface:\ ([a-z]+[0-9]+) ]]
currentPort="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

while read line; do
        if [[ $line = *Wi-Fi ]]; then
                read line
                wifiPort="${line##* }"
                break
        fi
done < <(networksetup -listallhardwareports)

if [[ "$wifiPort" = "$currentPort" ]]; then
        echo "I'm on WiFi!"
else
        echo "I'm NOT on WiFi!"
fi
```

Note that the `while read line` loop isn't particularly efficient, and a bash 4 `mapfile`/`readarray` would perform better. But the default version of bash in macOS is still 3.  :)